# How to populate array of structs, without using a line for code for each member?

Tags: c#, arrays, struct

I'm currently trying to find a better way to populate an array of structs.
first off, this is the data going in to making my struct

```
enum DataType
{
    Uint8, Uint16, Byte, Int16, Int32,
    TypeSatInfo, TypeCell, ByteArray
}
enum ReadWriteState
{
    ReadWrite, ReadOnly, WriteOnly
}
struct Parameter
{
   public string ParamName;
   public short ParamId;
   public  DataType Datatype;
   public ReadWriteState ReadWrite;

}
```

Then I have a class which should hold my populated array

```
static class Parameters
{
    public static Parameter[] Param = new Parameter[80];
}
```

and the last part I have is the function, which I want to use to populate the array.

```
void populateParameters()
{
    Parameters.Param[0].ParamName = "RevProtocol";
    Parameters.Param[0].ParamId = 0x0001;
    Parameters.Param[0].Datatype = DataType.Uint16;
    Parameters.Param[0].ReadWrite = ReadWriteState.ReadOnly;

    Parameters.Param[1].ParamName = "HwProtocol";
    Parameters.Param[1].ParamId = 0x0002;
    Parameters.Param[1].Datatype = DataType.Uint16;
    Parameters.Param[1].ReadWrite = ReadWriteState.ReadOnly;

    //keep this going until array is full.
}
```

I was hoping to do something like:

```
 Parameters.Param[80] = {{"RevProtocol", 0x0001, DataType.Uint16, ReadWriteState.ReadOnly},  
                         {"HwProtocol", 0x0002, DataType.Uint16, ReadWriteState.ReadOnly}}
```

By doing like this i hope to be able to populate the entire array at once, but i cant seem to find the right syntax for this. Is something like this possible?

Comment: As a tip, mutable structs are a common cause of problems and errors. If possible, I strongly suggest making it immutable and using a constructor, so: `new Parameter("RevProtocol", 0x0001, DataType.Uint16, ReadWriteState.ReadOnly)` etc (not setting the fields - in fact, public mutable fields are another part of the problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close. When using the object and collection initializers you still need to use the `new` keywords:

```
Parameters.Param = new Parameter[]
{
    new Parameter { ParamId = 0x0001, ParamName = "RevProtocol", Datatype = DataType.Byte },
    new Parameter { ParamId = 0x0002, ParamName = "HwProtocol", Datatype = DataType.TypeCell },
};
```

See in more details in the [Object and Collection Initializers (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384062.aspx)

Comment: I see, but do i do this in my class? or in my function?

Comment: @Claudi - wherever you want to initialize the array

Comment: Minor possible tweak: `new Parameter[] {...}` or `new [] {...}` means you don't need to update the number when you add/remove entries

Comment: @MarcGravell - Oh true :) updating

Comment: got it, is it possible to make my array "aware" of the struct order so i wont have to write member = value, for each parameter (there is a lot)

Comment: @Claudi as per the comment I've just added to the question: my advice there (because this is a struct  in particular, but possibly in general) would be to use a constructor or factory method that takes the values as positional arguments, rather than using member assignment

Comment: @GiladGreen my question doesnt include this info, but the ParamId is not following a incrementable order, your pre-edit answer did however answer my question, and the other part belongs in another thread i fear.

Comment: @Claudi - oh.. I just saw the example data you gave :)

Comment: @GiladGreen I think your answer was better without adresseing the ParamId issue. as the order of ID doesnt follow a certain pattern, and are not part of my question :).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, and as in your comments you ask how to do it without having to specify each property name, you could use a class instead of an struct,an add a custom constructor:

```
class Parameter
{
    public string ParamName;
    public short ParamId;
    public DataType Datatype;
    public ReadWriteState ReadWrite;

    public Parameter(string name,short id,DataType dt,ReadWriteState rw)
    {
        this.ParamName = name;
        this.ParamId = id;
        this.Datatype = dt;
        this.ReadWrite = rw;
    }
}
```

This way, you could initialize your array like this:

```
Parameters.Param = new Parameter[] 
        { new Parameter("RevProtocol", 0x0001, DataType.Uint16, ReadWriteState.ReadOnly),
          new Parameter("HwProtocol", 0x0002, DataType.Uint16, ReadWriteState.ReadOnly)};
```